# Create product for each color on catalog, but all link to one configurable

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1, product-attribute, color-swatches

I am currently using Magento for a fashion website. I am looking for an extension or some way to do the following:

PRODUCT 1 has 3 colors. Currently there is one configurable for PRODUCT 1 and then simples for each color, size variation. PRODUCT 1 shows on the category page 1 time.

What I want to do is have PRODUCT 1 show on the category page 3 times, one time for each of the colors. But still allow customers to view each color once entering the product.

Is there an extension that can show the product as 3 different ones on the category page, and then possibly link to the one configurable that is already created if clicked? This way I can keep the same number of products/ configurables in the backend, but the front end will show a product for each color variation.

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the extension you are looking for is [Pre-Select Colors Plus Swatches](http://cjmcreativedesigns.com/pre-select-colors-plus-swatches.html). You can find a working demo of the extension here:
http://preselectswatches.cjmcreativedesigns.com/products.html

There are 6 products shown in the demo. One is the configurable product and the other 5 are the simple products showing the various color options. You can set the catalog visibility of the products as you choose (i.e. hide configurable but show simples).